# How to handle rental income shared with my spouse on Schedule E

Tags: united-states, income-tax, partnership, schedule-e

I and my spouse are filling a separate 1040NR.

We have both our name on a property that we rent.

How do we fill the Schedule E if the income is shared between partners?

Let say for example that we do 50/50, do we divide all the amounts by 2 on the Schedule E?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be handled pretty much the same as if you were unrelated. The Schedule E has a place to indicate you are half owner. 
That said, there are rules that prevent you from filing separately to take advantage of a loss for which your combined income would be too high to deduct. Read the instructions carefully.